# How can I have a choice button display one value in the chat window but use a different one on the back end?

Tags: botframework

I have a prompt where I'm looking for a single value on the back end (GO), but some customers know this as GO and others as SO. I know I could add a synonym to the GO button, but that could be confusing for some customers and I want to display a separate SO button. No problem, I added another button with the title as 'SO' and value as 'GO'. If the user types SO, everything works as expected. But if they click on the SO button, it displays 'GO' in the chat window. It's a minor inconvenience but I'd rather this show the value they actually clicked on (while still sending 'GO' in the backend). Is there a way to accomplish this with choice buttons? Here is my prompt statement:

```js
return await step.prompt(CRITERIA_PROMPT, {
    prompt: 'Is this a GO, SO or PO number?',
    choices: [
        {value: 'GO', action: {type: 'imBack', title: 'GO', value:'GO'}, synonyms: ['General Order']},
        {value: 'GO', action: {type: 'imBack', title: 'SO', value:'GO'}, synonyms: ['Sales Order']},
        {value: 'PO', action: {type: 'imBack', title: 'PO', value:'PO'}, synonyms: ['Purchase Order']}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was a really simple fix, but as the answer wasn't apparent in the Choice documentation, I'm adding it here to help others. The first `value` in the choice is what is sent to the backend, and the `value` within the `action` object is what is displayed in the chat. So I just needed to update the value in the `action` object and everything started working as expected. The updated code is

```js
return await step.prompt(CRITERIA_PROMPT, {
    prompt: 'Is this a GO, SO or PO number?',
    choices: [
        {value: 'GO', action: {type: 'imBack', title: 'GO', value:'GO'}, synonyms: ['General Order']},
        {value: 'GO', action: {type: 'imBack', title: 'SO', value:'SO'}, synonyms: ['Sales Order']},
        {value: 'PO', action: {type: 'imBack', title: 'PO', value:'PO'}, synonyms: ['Purchase Order']}
    ]
});
```